# Getting Error: File 'ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'. while building Bundle file Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I want to build aab to upload CH Play but it always fails and shows a message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'root/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
```

I tried to search ic_launcher.png but my app does not use that name.
Note: I added 'ic_launcher.png' in the folder drawable but it still errors.

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you depend on a `jar` which should be an `aar`.

Jars don't have the concept of Android resources, so when the app bundle is built, it would consider the "res" directory as a a regular directory that would thus be packaged under "root".

Resources can be packaged in `aar` files, which would then be packaged properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think the issue is because I was importing another project to my project and it will be a duplicate folder "res" so I cannot build an aab file. 

Can you help me confirm the way to fix it: 
- First: Export another project to an `aar` file.
- Second: Import the `aar` file to my project.
 Is that correct or not?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Can you import the project as a library? If that doesn't work, I'd reach out to the Android Studio team via the issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

'res' is android application reserved directory name, try to change 'root/res' for another name

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But in my code, It doesn't have a "root/res" folder, I search all folders and cannot find it. Do you have any other suggestions?